# Spring JPA: Prevent deleting if relations still exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have two entities:

Table **activity**:

```
|id|milestone_id|..|
| 1|3           |..|
| 2|3           |..|
```

Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="activity")
public class Activity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Milestone milestone;
}
```

and table **milestone**:

```
|id|..|
| 3|..|
```

Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="milestone")
public class Milestone implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "milestone")
    private List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Now, when I delete a milestone 3, my Activity's are kept intact. However, the milestone_id still points to the related Milestone that was deleted already.

Now when I retrieve the activities again I get this error:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find nl.geodan.vergunningen.manager.domain.Milestone with id 3
```

Seems logical to me.

What I want however is that the Milestone can't get deleted, because the `milestone_id` on the activity table is `optional = false`.

What did I miss?
Should I reload the activities? Should I use some kind of CascadeType?

Comment: The point is that you don't want to let delete `Milestone` object if there is any `Activity` pointing to it, yes?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski yes, i want to prevent it from happening

Comment: Use a foreign key between the tables wouldn't work?

Comment: @Paolof76 I didn't try. What do you suggest exactly?

Comment: Well, if you don't want a milestone without an activity, you create a foreign key on milestone referring activity.id

Comment: @Paolof76 adding `@JoinColumn(name = "milestoneId")` to Activity didn't have any effect. (That's what you meant right?) The idea is to prevent deleting a milestone if it still has one or more activities related to it.

Comment: uhm... have you tried to really add a foreign key on the database? This would not allow the inconsistency (but also you got an exception if you don't manage it programmatically)

Comment: @HannesSmit foreign keys are only generated during database ddl generation phase, so adding annotations won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to your database schema - I've tried [reproducing your problem](https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/94d1b56d81f58b2d7435) and I am sure you don't use application generated schema, but already existing one **without foreign keys defined**. See the output.txt file where `ConstraintViolationException` occurs.

You can add foreign key to your database by executing proper `SQL` command:

```
ALTER TABLE Activity
ADD FOREIGN KEY (milestone_id)
REFERENCES Milestone(id)
```

Or just change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property (`in case of spring boot`) to `create`. If you use raw Spring then it would be property of `Hibernate` itself - `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`.

If you don't have an access or privileges to schema you can handle it programically, but this is certainly workaround and just smells bad - one solution would be to check for dependencies everytime you delete `Milestone` entity, the other one would involve putting `@PreDelete` listener in `Milestone` entity:

```
@PreRemove
private void preRemove() {
    if (!activities.isEmpty()) {
        throw new LinkedActivityExistsException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maciej, you analysis is correct!! I ran the contextLoads test in Debug level and lookedup the ddl in the log. That, indeed, differed from my handwritten ddl. It's just something I forgot about. Thanks!